# Why is $\phi : \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},G) \to G$ given by $ f \mapsto f(1)$ surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was working on showing $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},G) \cong G$ for $G$ abelian. The proposed map given by evaluating a given $f \in \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},G)$ at $1$ is easily seem to be a homomorphism and an injection, but I am stuck on showing it's surjective. I believe I have to use the fact that $f(n) = (f(1))^n$. If $g\in G$ and $f(1)=a$, then I don't see an immediate relation between $f(1)=a$ and $g$. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given $g\in G$, we can define a homomorphism $f\colon\mathbb Z\to G$, $n\mapsto g^n$. Then $\phi(f)=g$.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to any group is freely and uniquely determined by where $1$ maps to.  In other words for any $g\in G$ there is a unique homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\to G$ satisfying by $f(1)=g$.  Since $f$ is supposed to be a homomorphism and $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}$, there is at most one such $f$ satisfying this property, namely $f(n)=g^n$.  This gives uniqueness.  Finally, simply notice that the map $f$ is well defined, which gives existence.

Comment: I was thinking around these lines as well, but didn't feel comfortable simply asserting $f(1)=g$. How are we sure an $f$ exists satisfying the above?

Comment: The idea is we "try" to do it and then check that it actually works.  If $f(1)=g$ then by the homomorphism property $f(n)=g^n$ for any integer $n$.  So we just take this to be the definition of the map, and then we need to check that it is well defined.  In other words if $n=m$ then we need that $g^n=g^m$.  But of course this is true for any integers $n$ and $m$.

Comment: Alright, I think that makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

That comes from the general characterisation of free modules over a commutative ring $R$:
$$\operatorname{Hom}_R(R^{(I)},M)\simeq M^I$$
Here $\mathbf Z$ is a free $\mathbf Z$-module of rank $1$.